# Search array elements by index postgresql

Tags: postgresql

is it possible to somehow get elements from the postgresql array by index? I did not find anything sensible on the Internet on this issue. I have a table:

```
CREATE TABLE groups_timetable(id SMALLINT PRIMARY KEY, timetable VARCHAR(40)[]);

INSERT INTO groups_timetable(id, timetable) VALUES(1, '{"math, physical culture, programming", "math, economic theory"}');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just get element by using index -

```
select timetable[1] from groups_timetable --where 1 is index
```

> Note - The arrays are 1 indexed.

[DBFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/dbe38/2)

Comment: thank you very much! And if, for example, I have several schedules, how can I get the first index of the array of the first ID, and not the second?

Comment: You can just filter the records with `where` clause.